# Integral reducible to Bessel function

Tags: bessel-functions

I wonder whether one could reduce the following integral to some combination of special (e.g. Bessel) functions: $$\int_{m}^{\infty}d\epsilon \exp\left(-s\epsilon\right)\left( \epsilon^{2}-m^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left( \epsilon^{2}-\lambda m^{2}\right)^{1/2}$$

The integral without the last term in the integrand reduces to a well know integral representation of  $K_{1}$, but I can not figure out if there is a clever variable substitution which brings the integral above to something better known.

Comment: I cannot even do $\int_{4}^{\infty }\!{{\rm e}^{-\epsilon}}\sqrt {{\epsilon}^{2}-16}
\sqrt {{\epsilon}^{2}-4}\,{\rm d}\epsilon$